# Firefox - empty ul html element displaying even though I don't want it to

Tags: css

I have a ul element where the li items inside dynamically change. If there are no li items I want to box to disapear entirely. However I don't want to use a JavaScript solution of writing hide()/show() on the box.

How can I make the ul box disappear or fade if there are no contents?

```
> <ul id ="list"></ul>
```

[image]

```
ul {
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    z-index: 999;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I can provide additional info if needed

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem [in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pu2ssgh/). Could you maybe show us a live demo of this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `overflow-y: scroll;` with `overflow-y: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `:empty` pseudo-selector.

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty)

```
ul:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Neat solution! I didn't know about the `:empty` pseudo-selector!

Comment: Looks like the correct answer but keep in mind that it's a CSS3 selector, and has some known issues with IE. Take a look here (at the bottom of the page under 'known issues': http://caniuse.com/#search=empty

`IE9-IE11 supports :empty but will not repaint/relayout the page if content is added/removed from an :empty selected element`

Comment: Besides that the author has broken the `ul-tag` by setting `overflow-y` to `scroll`, so adding `ul:empty` with `display: none` is a fix for a issue introduced by himself..